# F# getting specific element from list of tuples

Tags: list, f#

Assuming the declarations below, how would I be able to take the list `ats` and get the `ints` from it, if I wanted to check whether they were all positive numbers for example? A hint is greatly appreciated.

```
type Item = string
type ItemList = Item * int

let ad1 = ("machine", 2)
let ad2 = ("coffee", 1)
let ad3 = ("washer", 2)
let ats = [ad1; ad2; ad3; ad1; ad2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let ints = ats |> List.map snd

let allPositive = ints |> List.forall (fun x -> x > 0)
```

Comment: @Khaine775 it's all about applying higher order functions. :-) Anyways, if you want to factor out the x, you can make it even shorter: `ints |> List.forall  ((<) 0)`

Comment: Neat. A follow-up question could be: If I only wanted to get the `int` value of the `items` in the list with a certain name, for example of I wanted to just get the the `ints` from the tuples containing `coffee`?

Comment: `let coffeeInts = ats |> List.filter (fst >> (=) "coffee") |> List.map snd`

Comment: Notice how I composed the `fst` function with the `(=) "coffee"` function. I could have written that the long way around as `fun x -> (fst x) = "coffee"`, but I find that this particular way of composing filter functions is more expressive and easier (for me) to read. If you find the more-explicit `fun x -> ...` syntax easier to read, use that instead.